# include local.properties file in android jenkins build

Tags: android, jenkins, cicd

I am trying to set up jenkins pipeline for android app. we are not commiting the local.properties file on git server for security reasons. now the problem is this local.properties file contains few variables that i am accessing from build.gradle and since it is not committed, jenkin build unable to locate this file and build fails.
How can i add this configuration in my jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by using
`echo "dev_flavor=\"dev\"" >> local.properties` 
command before gradle build command in jenkins job

 **build step > Invoke Gradle script**